# SpriteKit Nodes with Gravity False tilted in place

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I'm building a menu Game Scene where I have a Logo and 4 buttons, all of those have a SKPhysicsBody with the rectangle size of the image.
All of those I only set:

```
logo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: logo.size)
logo.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

Full code of creating the objects (all are the same)

```
logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "logo")
logo.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
logo.name = "logo"
logo.zPosition = 2
logo.size = CGSize(width: 309, height: 272)
logo.setScale(Generic.utilities.getScale())
self.addChild(logo)
logo.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 - logo.size.width/2, y: self.frame.height - logo.size.height - 40)
logo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: logo.size)
logo.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

and during a button press I change all the nodes affectedByGravity to true so they can fall of the screen and new elements can come in.

The problem I'm having is that when I run the app, the elements are all shifted/tilted on the screen and not in their original position
[image: Tilted Nodes]

All I wanted is for them to stay in their position until I click one of the buttons and then they can fall off the screen.

Any reason why when I set a physics body and affectedByGravity they all tilt like this?

Comment: You need to show more code...like how you create the objects, what your gravity is set to, the entire physicsbody code for at least one of the objects. I was able to create a quick demo with 3 squares (2 added In the scene editor, one added in code, and with 1 with physics set in the scene editor, and the other 2 with physics create at runtime. The one that was added in the scene editor spins slightly on scene load (no idea why). give some more info and we can figure this out

Comment: @RonMyschuk Added more code to the question

Comment: can you show the gravity settings

Comment: @RonMyschuk that's it, there are no more code for this. plain and simple create and add to view.

Comment: Sorry, I'm at a loss. I pasted the code into my test project and it works as expected. I don't mean to question your "no more code", but there has to be something else in the code or the sks scene file (if you are using one) that is causing this. Currently the 2 things I would question are 1) does your getScale func have something to do with this? 2) are there other physics objects on the scene overlapping each other? If they are they might be pushing each other to a different position and angle in a fight for supremacy :(

Comment: looks to me like your elements are overlapping each other and the collision tests are moving your sprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Thanks to @RonMyschuk and @Knight0fDragon I found out (didn't know before) that I could add to my Scene loading the following:

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

Which add border lines around the physicsBody of your nodes, that way you can see them interacting. And by doing that I saw that the physicsBody of one of my nodes was completely in a different position then it should

[image: Borderline around physicsBody]

By taking care of this issue, everything went back to normal